# Entity Framework SDF database size issue

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I am using SQL Server Compact edition with Entity Framework for one of my project. I'm reading files from server and saving it to my database. The problem is that database size becomes big (i.e. exceeds the max database size) and application crashes with the message:

> entity framework underlying provider failed on open
>   database exceeds max size

I read from various sites and tried to add:

```
Max Database Size=1024
```

to my connection string but it says keyword not supported. I do not want to use `.mdf` as client has to install SQL Server also.

Here is my connection string:

```
<add name="Entities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/DBModel.csdl|res://*/DBModel.ssdl|res://*/DBModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0;provider connection string=&quot;data source=|DataDirectory|\DB.sdf&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: Maybe try to store the files **outside** the `.sdf` database file....

Comment: An option is to look at using `localdb`.  The client will still need to install something, but it's not full-blown SQL Server, and you could bundle its installation into your own.  It supports database sizes up to 10GB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change connection string:

```
<add name="Entities" 

  connectionString="metadata=res://*/DBModel.csdl|res://*/DBModel.ssdl|res://*/DBModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0;provider connection string=&quot;data source=|DataDirectory|\DB.sdf;Max database size=4091&quot;" 
 providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Also note that the max size for a SQL Compact database is 4 GB